# Where does Google Chrome save temporary pdf files?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I was wondering where does Google Chrome save pdf documents that it opens in the browser itself. I know those get deleted if we dont save them and close the browser.

I looked into chrome temporary folder at ~/.cache/google-chrome, but couldnt find any pdf there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** This no longer works since the Chrome disk cache format [has changed](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/disk-cache-v3)

---

It's in that directory, all right. Just uses a random string for filenames. Test it out:

```
find ~/.cache/google-chrome -type f -exec file {} + | grep PDF
```

For example:

```
$ find .cache/google-chrome/ -type f -exec file {} + | grep PDF
.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/f_004bf0:       PDF document, version 1.5
.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/f_004c01:       PDF document, version 1.4
```

Comment: thank you, I was actually searching with file names, so missed it

Comment: Just wondering... didn't it all use to be stored in the `/tmp` folder?

Comment: @RickyRobinson not in the past couple of years, at least, I think. I've had problems with Chrome filling up student's quotas for at least that long.

Comment: Does that find command search sub-directories? My ~/.cache/google-chrome/ folder has multiple sub-folders, each with multiple sub-folders, so I was wondering how deep it would search.

I didn't find any PDF files, although I had just closed one, so is there anywhere else that Chrome might store files it's had open?

Comment: @JamesBB as you can see from the output, it went at least 3 subdirectories deep. `find` recurses by default, unless you used the `-maxdepth` option.

Comment: Does this method work any more? I tried and all I see in chrome cache are data files. My version is 77.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work any more because the file format of the Chrome cache changed.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Chrome cache directory `$HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache` on Linux contains one file per cache entry named `<16 char hex>_0` in ["simple entry format"](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/disk_cache/simple/simple_entry_format.h#18):

- 20 Byte SimpleFileHeader
- key (i.e. the URI)
- payload (the raw file content i.e. the PDF in our case)
- SimpleFileEOF record
- HTTP headers
- SHA256 of the key (optional)
- SimpleFileEOF record

You therefore cannot simply use `file` to determine the file type (it will just detect `data`), but must search for the PDF header. This will list all PDFs in the cache directory:

```
grep -Rl '%PDF' $HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache
```

**Note:** This may give you false positives in case the string `%PDF` appears somewhere in a file which isn't a PDF

**Note:** If you're not using the default Chrome profile, replace `Default` with the profile name, e.g. `Profile 1`.

`evince` will happily read the cache file directly, without having to strip the header.

If you do want to extract the original PDF, save the following script as `extractpdf.py`:

```py
def main(cachefile):
    with open(cachefile, 'rb') as f:
        s = f.read()
    with open(cachefile + '.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(s[s.find(b'%PDF'):s.rfind(b'%%EOF')+5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

And call it as `python3 extractpdf.py <cache file>`